# Legenda em imagens CSS e HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, imagem, front-end

Estou com uma duvida gostaria de saber como posso colocar uma legenda em uma imagem dentro de uma div , Quem poder me ajudar agradeço , Muito Obrigado !!!!

As informações estão a baixo :

```css
.ar img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 130px;
 top: 946px;
 right: 200px;
 font-size:36px;
}
.ar img:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

```html
<div class="ar">
<img "ar" src="imagens/ar.png" alt="Arcondicinados" title="Ar condicionados e Climatizadores"  />
</div>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço para dispor do título por cima da imagem - bootstrap?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194253/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-dispor-do-t%c3%adtulo-por-cima-da-imagem-bootstrap)

Comment: Consegui Muito Obrigado pela ajuda também !!!! Vou salvar esse que você me recomendou e muito interessante também .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se era isso que você queria. Caso precise ajustar a legenda, mexa na posição no css.

```css
.posicionado {
 right: 200px;
 position: absolute;
}
.ar img {
 width: 200px;
 height: 130px;
 font-size:36px;
}
.ar img:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

```html
<div class="ar posicionado">
<img src="https://c.mlcdn.com.br/1500x1500/ar-condicionado-split-lg-9000-btus-frio-filtro-3msmile-tsnc092w4w0-011474800.jpg" alt="Ar-condicionados" title="Ar condicionados e Climatizadores"  />
</div>
<br>
<h4 class="posicionado">Sua legenda</h4>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda deu certinho !!! Vlw Abraços